# <a> on hover initiates undesired hover effect. What is going on here, and is there a way to stop it?

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7o0zmrmq/6/

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
}
.visible {

}
.visible:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

In the example, the `<li>` of class visible has the hover selector and should show the desired child `<ul>`.

While that works all well and good, hovering over just the link itself below also initiates the transition effect while setting opacity to 1.

Comment: It's because hovering over the child subsequently means that you are hovering over the parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try making them siblings:

```
<ul class="container">
<h2 class="visible">Visible Hover</h2>
  <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>



.hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
}

.visible:hover + ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Also note, you'll want to set `visibility: hidden` when it's not showing, else your cursor will still know there is a link there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use display none (here your jsfiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/7o0zmrmq/10/)

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="visible">Visible Hover 
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
  display:none;
}
.visible {

}
.visible:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This will destroy the transition

Answer (score 0):

Hovering over the child means that you're also hovering over it's parent.
There are several ways to solve this.

Here are two examples.

You could add a span within your visible `li` and add your hover to this.

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.visible > span:hover + ul{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="visible"><span>Visible Hover</span>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or you could add a height to your container and add `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.visible:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.visible {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
}
.visible:hover {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="visible">Visible Hover 1
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li </ul>
```